# How to add form validation along with alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, alert

I'm working on a simple sign up form. So far I have the form validation working but I am not sure how to get the alerts working as well. The idea is to have the user fill out their info, click submit, and an alert with their given information will pop up. How can I add an alert to make this work?

HTML:

```
<div class="sign-up">
                <form>
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" id="suName" required>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="suEmail" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="suPassword" required>
                    <input class="submit-button su-submit" type="submit" id="mySUButton">
                </form>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
function setBindings() {

    $(".sign-up form #mySIButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var suName = $(".sign-up form #suName").val(),
            email = $(".sign-up form #suEmail").val(),
            pw = $(".sign-up form #suPassword").val(),

            alert("This is your entered information: " + suName.value + ", " + email.value + ", " + pw + ".");
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    setBindings();
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but it can give an idea: [Bootstrap Wizard](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors that's why your code is not working. you can achieve this by simply writing the following jquery code:

```
 $("#mySUButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var suName = $("#suName").val();
    var email = $("#suEmail").val();
    var pw = $("#suPassword").val();
    if(suName=="" || email=="" || pw=="")
    {
        alert("All fields required");
        return false;
    }
    else if (IsEmail(email) == false)
    {
       alert("Invalid Email ID");
       return false;
    }
    alert("This is your entered information: " + suName+ ", " + email + ", " + pw + ".");
   });

function IsEmail(email) {
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So when I add your code, the alert works but the form validation doesn't. Is there a way to have them both working?

Comment: what validation do you want. are you asking for required field validations? @Hank.Ball

Comment: I'd like for the form to make sure the user is filling out each box, along with making sure the email they provide has the proper symbols (@).

Comment: Oh terrific, I now have both the validation and alerts working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not need `.value` again the `jQuery` function `.val()` returns value

Try with this:

```
var suName = $("#suName").val();
          var  email = $("#suEmail").val();
         var   pw = $("#suPassword").val();

            alert("This is your entered information: " + suName+ ", " + email+ ", " + pw + ".");
```

Comment: I took away the .value but the alert still doesn't show. Do I need to move the alert to a different location?

Comment: It says there is an error in the line of the alert?

Comment: You gave a comma instead of semi colon

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up you should never save passwords as a string, and be able to reflect it back to the user (like in an alert). You always want to use a passsword hashing algorithm (bcrypt is usually best in my opinion), as storing plaintext passwords in your database makes them very accessible to exploit.

That being said, I think you need an event handler, like for when submit is clicked, for your javascript function to be called, and the alert to pop up. As is, it should submit to your database (assuming your back end is set up) but I don't think the javascript function will ever be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onSubmit` in form tag to validate form

```js
function setBindings() {
        var suName = $("#suName").val();
        var email = $("#suEmail").val();
        var pw = $("#suPassword").val();
        var isValid = true;
        if(suName==""){
          alert("Name can't be empty");
          isValid = false;
        }
        if(email=="" && isValid){
          alert("Email can't be empty");
          isValid = false;
        }
        if(pw=="" && isValid){
          alert("Password can't be empty");
          isValid = false;
        }
        if(pw.length < 6  && isValid){
          alert("Password can't be less than 6 character");
          isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sign-up">
                <form onSubmit="return setBindings();">
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" id="suName" >
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="suEmail"  placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="suPassword" >
                    <input class="submit-button su-submit" type="submit" id="mySUButton">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I removed HTML validation, `required` attribute to test javascript validation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your code worked for me as well. Thank you!